# Terminal Failing to login

Tags: macos, terminal

Suddenly, when I attempted to create a new terminal window, it fails. It does nothing for about a minute then shows only this:

```
Login incorrect
login:
```

Typing in my username doesn't work. I get the same message. Terminal was already up and running in another window. I just can't create any more.

My editor, IntelliJ, has a built in terminal and that's running fine.

Comment: And it cleared itself up after 30 minutes. Weird. There was a scary minute when the login screen was exhibiting the same behavior. If anyone has a theory as to what might have happened, I'd be interested in hearing it.

Comment: Your login shell might be broken. Try going to Terminal **Preferences** > **Startup tab**, and check that "Default Login Shell" Is selected. if it is, select "Command (complete path)" And type `login username`. You might have to enter password every time you view terminal.

Comment: (Waited for enough rep to comment) a similar thing happened to me when I was using Terminal while a system update was installing; commands suddenly stopped working and I started to panic. After the update, which presumably had affected binaries, paths, etc, things went back to normal. I have the feeling this might have been what happened in your case. Did it work again?

Answer (score 5):

This has happened to me in the past and just happened again on a Mac running High Sierra (10.13.5) that is bound to an Active Directory domain.

Turns out it was caused by an active Cisco IPSec VPN connection. The VPN connection likely hijacked my DNS settings and broke local name resolution that relied on using the AD server's DNS.

It also broke access to the Users & Groups System Preference panel.

Try disconnecting your VPN and reopening Terminal.

Comment: My company is using a new VPN and it has been messing with my company Macbook a lot recently. This did the trick for me. Thank you.

Comment: I know our vpn has been overwriting the /etc/hosts file when launching, but today was the first time I ran into this. had walked away for a bit and the vpn had become disconnected. when I tried to start a new terminal the f5 big ip was animating 3 dots in the menu bar. turn that off, and all goes back to normal. odd...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; the computer had been attached to Active Directory and the account had been disabled. I went ahead and disabled Active Directory by going into **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > unlocking the system to make changes and select **Network Account Server:** and just deleted the Active Directory account.

Comment: this was the cause when i experienced this problem.  thanks (kind of obvious once you say it, but i didn't even think about it)

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch: you might have too many pty's open (pseudo-teletype).

Happened to me while using Xcode, which apparently opened up too many terminal sessions in the background and prevented me from opening a new one.

If this happens again, you could try

```
  sudo sysctl -w kern.tty.ptmx_max=255
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Terminal preferences plist did the trick for me.

```
mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.OLD.plist
```

It gets regenerated next time you run Terminal.